Chain multiple ajax requests in website to show more pages and get full list in single page
I would like to get the full page https://icomarks.ai/icos/ when scrolling down while clicking Show More button. It should show around 8000 elements.
The Show More button activates a POST request https://icomarks.ai/icos/ajax_more.
My current attempt is
import json
from pprint import pprint

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



all_them_links = []
offset = 0

while True:
    with requests.Session() as session:
        req = session.post('https://icomarks.ai/icos/ajax_more',
                           data={'offset': offset})
        response = json.loads(req.content)
        offset = offset + int(response['offset'])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response["content"], "html.parser")
        pprint(['response', len(response["content"])])
        found_links = soup.find_all("a", class_="icoListItem__title")
        print(len(all_them_links))
        print(f"Found {len(found_links)} links")
        for a in found_links:
            all_them_links.append([a["href"], a.get_text()])
        if len(found_links) == 0:
            print("No more links found")
            break

but the code stops when all_them_links reaches length 180.
EDIT
setting offset = int(response['offset']) allows the code to proceed but now it stops when all_them_links reaches length 1900.
